# Is it possible to make a redirect rule in the routerjs file to create a vanity route

Tags: ember.js

To speak specifically, I have a URL to one page on a website but the URL is somewhat long and ugly.

It might look a little bit like this

`mywebsite.com/all-products/hats/golf-caps`

however, my marketing team feels this URL is too long and wants me to add a "prettified" url like this:

`mywebsite.com/golf-caps`

But all it would really do is redirect to the original route.

Is there a way to do this in ember.js? Or is this a bad practice? Ideally, I would only need to modify the router file rather than create a completely new route in my application just to perform a redirect.

Comment: Would the link: `mywebsite.com/r/golf-caps` be ok? I'm thinking a generic route `/r/:short` that contains a bunch of re-direct rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the server then I would handle this there. It's nice to be able to send the correct `308 permanent redirect` header so search indexing lines up and most backend routing solutions seem to have concept this built in.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware of you need to create a new route with a `beforeModel()` hook containing the redirect. But I don't think that this adds a lot of complexity. It's basically `ember generate route golf-caps` and edit the created `app/routes/golf-caps.js` to contain:

```js
export default class GolfCapsRoute extends Route {
  beforeModel() {
    this.transitionTo('all-products/hats/golf-caps');
  }
}
```

You may want to delete the route's template `app/templates/golf-caps.hbs` as that won't be rendered in any case.

If you have more than one redirect, you may want to consider adding a [wild-card route](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_wildcard--globbing-routes) that catches all requests. This could do the redirects based on a map for multiple paths and render a not-found page if there isn't any redirect registered for the path.

Answer (score 0):

Ember has [`resetNamespace`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.13/classes/EmberRouter/methods?anchor=map) ([guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resetting-nested-route-namespace)).

```js
this.route('all-products', { resetNamespace: true, path: '/' }, function() {
  this.route('categories', { resetNamespace: true, path: ':category_id' }, function() {
    this.route('subcategories', { path: ':subcategory_id' });
  });
});
```

I'm not sure how `resetNamespace will work two levels deep like that though. Especially since you have something meaningful in the second level, i.e.,`hats`. Your ember router needs that to know which 'category' to request from the server.

For example `golf-caps` 'subcategory' could be in two 'categories'. If someone navigated directly to `mysite.com/golf-caps` your server would have no way to know which `golf-caps` to show, the ones from `hats` or the ones from `accessories`.

The only way you'd be able to collapse them down is if all your subcategories were truly unique. In which case, then yes, do just get rid of the category level.

Assuming you still need the category, I think you'll just be able to get rid of `all-products` in your URL:

```js
this.route('all-products', { resetNamespace: true, path: '/' }, function() {
  this.route('categories', { path: ':category_id' }, function() {
    this.route('subcategories', { path: ':subcategory_id' });
  });
});
```